# How to get better topology on a Ellipse corner

Tags: topology

I have made a circle on a flat area then inset it. And then to imitate a speedometre I have extruded the mesh selection. As seen on the left bottom edge of the topology the ends are a bit sharp, and on the right more circular. I used the knife tool, rather than adding another loop, but made Ngons and some triangles, I'm trying to clean the topology up, can anyone post how the topology could be better?

PS: adding a loop towards the down topology can fix this issue, but Ill be adding lots of the semicircle extruded groves on a larger surface, and could possible ruin other parts of the mesh, so this is why I'd like to know how to get a better topology just in that section.

[image]

Comment: so do you want the ends to be sharp or circular?

Comment: I need the ends to be circular, but without the extra loop passing as @Vclidu suggested.

Comment: Circular end Is native result od subsurf ... extra loop you need for square end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proposition if you want the end to be circular:

[image]

Begin with a plane, subdivide (3 cuts), extrude inwards, then *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Extrude inwards again, fill the center, bevel the circle (3 segments):

[image]

Rearrange the topology, then extrude down the circle, bevel the edges, etc:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is good to have one extra loop following a circle embos ...

Here I deleted all front vertices except two inne loops.
Second inner loop make circled with *To Sphere* (Shift+Alt+S+1)
Extrude scale several times for desired result ...

[image]
[image]

To make ends more squary add edge loop Ctrl+R and slide ...

[image]

To make top edges sharp – select them plus end face and Crease Shift+E to 1 ...

[image]

[image]